# vue.js VeeValidate - custom validator correctly compiles errors but does not toggle error class

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vee-validate

I've written a custom validator like this:

```
    created () {
        this.$validator.extend('validateCert', {
            getMessage: (field) => {
                return field + ' is not a valid certificate';
            },
            validate: (value) => {
                return value.startsWith('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----') && value.endsWith('-----END CERTIFICATE-----');
            }
        });
    }
```

I've attached it to a text area inside a modal:

```
    <div class="pb-3 mr-4">
        <b-form-textarea 
            type="text"
            v-validate="'required|validateCert'"
            data-vv-validate-on="change"
            v-model.trim="signedCerts[index]"
            data-vv-scope="uploadCert"
            :name="'certificate_' + index"
            :class="[{'is-invalid': errors.has('certificate_' + index)}]"
            rows="15"/>
        <fr-validation-error :validatorErrors="errors" :fieldName="'certificate_' + index"></fr-validation-error>
    </div>
```

Then - on button click I do the following:

```
uploadCerts (event) {
    let idmInstance = this.getRequestService(),
        body = {
            fromCSR: true,
            certs: _.each(this.signedCerts, (cert) => { 
                JSON.stringify(cert); 
            })
    };

this.$validator.validateAll('uploadCert').then((valid) => {
    // Prevent modal from closing
    event.preventDefault();

    if (valid) { // some more logic
```

If I inspect the computed errors object, I will see my failed validation:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "19",
            "field": "certificate_0",
            "msg": "certificate_0 is not a valid certificate",
            "rule": "validateCert",
            "scope": "uploadCert",
            "regenerate": {
                "_custom": {
                    "type": "function",
                    "display": "<span>ƒ</span> regenerate()"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and the value of 'valid' (either true or false) is accurate at all times.  I'm just not seeing my error classes being triggered.

Comment: Where do you define `errors`?  Is is `reactive`?  Is is defined in your `data` section? How do you mutate it?  If you use the index operator `[]`, your logic will not get called.  You will need to use `Vue.set` if that is the case.

Comment: `errors` is provided by veeValidate.

Comment: I don't see anything bad in your code at glance. I always check if `errors` is present before using it to avoid exceptions when the component is still loading, like, in your case:  `[{'is-invalid': errors && errors.has('certificate_' + index)}]`. But I don't think this has something to do with your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to completely answer the question because part of it depends on what happens in `fr-validation-error`, but I think the problem is how you're using scopes.

When you define `data-vv-scope="uploadCert"` that means that every reference to field-name has to be prefaced by `uploadCert.` in `errors`.  So when you specify in your `:class` that `errors.has('certificates_'+index)`, you have to change that to `errors.has('uploadCert.certificates_'+index)`.

Here's how it would look in full (minus the bootstrap-vue and multiple fields bits):

```
    <textarea
      v-validate="'required|validateCert'"
      data-vv-validate-on="change"
      data-vv-scope="uploadCert"
      v-model.trim="signedCert"
      name="certificate"
      class="form-control"
      :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.has('uploadCert.certificate') }"
      rows="10"
    >
    </textarea>
```

Full working example for one certificate upload field:  https://codesandbox.io/s/z2owy0r2z3